# How to play again MediaPlayer after release()

Tags: android, button, android-mediaplayer

when I click the `ImageButton` there was a sound. but I need to `release()` so I can play all the button sound. But when I click twice the button my app has stopped.

Here my code:

```
ImageButton btnda = (ImageButton) findViewById(MyActivity.this, R.id.daa);
    btnda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final MediaPlayer soundda = MediaPlayer.create(DaftarHuruf.this);
            soundda.start();
            soundda.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

here from android monitor error display:

```
07-20 13:32:32.053 25594-25594/com.example.john.lontaraapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.john.lontaraapp, PID: 25594
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                             at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1177)
                                                                             at com.example.john.lontaraapp.DaftarHuruf$8.onClick(DaftarHuruf.java:100)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:949)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:744)
```

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. By accepting an answer to the question you are telling others that the question is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your

```
final MediaPlayer soundda = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.da);
```

inside `onClick()` before

```
 soundda.start();
```

so you create a `MediaPlayer` before you need to play it regardless of if you released it, or not created yet.

Also use not `this`, but `<YourActivityName>.this`, because you will move code inside `OnClickListener`, and `this` will be treated as an `OnClickListener` object, and you need a `Context` object

Comment: create(this, R.raw.ka);   cannot resolve method. are my code is right ?

Comment: @Adhiwhit, I don't know, you didn't show the updated code. Only the `create(this, R.raw.ka);`, which does not make sense.

Comment: I was updated the code, from my android studio, create(this, R.raw.ka); is cannot resolve method

Comment: @Adhiwhit, that is not what I suggested to do. Isuggested `final MediaPlayer soundda = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.da);` , not `create(this, R.raw.ka);`

Comment: @Adhiwhit, ok, also use not `this`, but `<YourActivityName>.this`

Comment: the problem is same

Comment: @Adhiwhit, please update the code in the question, I can't see what is wrong not seeing the code.

Comment: @Adhiwhit, what is `DaftarHuruf`?

Comment: my activity name

Comment: @Adhiwhit why you removed the secont parameter of the `create` method? `, R.raw.da`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `release()` releases the player and the associated resources. If you want to play again you should do: `soundda = new MediaPlayer();`
and init it again... so set listeners and so on.

Comment: After release() was called and you want to again play